# Need Explaination in this word guessing javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to check wether the input that I give is being correctly executed, but why does the if statement always return false even i give the correct input?
I don't want the solution only the need explanation. Please is there anyone who could explain? I've included my html input elements Just in case something wrong with it.

```
<script>

    var text1 = ["O","K","E"];
    var text2 = ["_","_","_"];

    function guess(j){
        for(i=0; i < text1.length; i++){
            if(j == text1[i]){
                text2[i] = j;
                console.log(text2[i])
            }
            else {
                    console.log("try again")
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `why does the if statement always return false` because it's a ghost if statement!!!

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: The code was not formatted correctly and therefore the biggest part was not shown. I fixed that for you

Comment: there you go, bad connection. im using input tag in html to input text & submit

Comment: The condition will be true if you pass in e.g. `"O"`. Are you saying that's not the case? I doubt that. You are likely not passing valid input.

Comment: <quote> statement always return false even i give the correct input </quote>

Comment: That's not true. You probably get confused because "try again" is printed in any case. If you guessed a letter, it will print it twice, if not, three times. You need to print outside of the loop and set a boolean in your if / else that signifies you have or have not found a match.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/me00cvfc/. Input is `'O'` and `O` is logged to the console. So clearly the condition is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @Unglückspilz in code:

```
// extra "K" to show how to handle multiple finds
var text1 = ["O","K","E","K"];
var text2 = ["_","_","_","_"];

function guess(j){
    // a flag to set if one or more letters were found
    found = false;
    // check every letter in the haystack against given needle
    for(i=0; i < text1.length; i++){
        if(j == text1[i]){
            // exchange underbar against found letter(s)
            text2[i] = j;
            console.log(text2[i]);
            // set flag to true
            found = true;
        }
    }
    // no letter was correct
    if(!found){
        console.log("try again");
    }
    // return boolean if anything was found (but not how many)
    return found;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, it still logging "try again" even if you input one of the array string

Comment: ??? If you run `guess("O")` it should print out "O" at the console as it does here in the Scratchpad of a recent Firefox and in "node". If you give it `guess("K")` ist should prin "K" on the console twice, as it it does here and finally, if you run `guess("g")` it should print "try again". The returns are `true`, `true`, and `false` respectively.